# Adding conditional class to EmberJS handlebar element

Tags: css, ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use a EmberJS handlebar texture element and conditionally add a css class to it. Code looks like this:

```html
{{textarea class={{if isBlue 'blue-css' 'green-css'}} }}
```

This does not work. The inner handlebars expression is inserted literally into the html, but I can use an html textarea:

```html
<textarea class={{if isBlue 'blue-css' 'green-css'}} ></textarea>
```

How can I do this using an EmberJS handlebars expression, if at all?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try,

```
{{textarea classNameBindings="isBlue:blue-css:green-css"}}
```

as explained here [docs](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/views/customizing-a-views-element/)

Comment: Thank you. I'm still very new to EmberJS and just missed it.